# CSS, if html is value, change color

Tags: jquery, css

Sorry For being unclear, what I mean is this.

Currently on page load I fetch the links with a certain id, I check my database, then json back the result into the link. So Essentially:

```
<a href="#" class="switcher" id="Site_Gallery-<?php echo $item->id; ?>">...loading....</a>
```

Becomes either:

```
<a id="Site_Gallery-563" class="switcher" href="#">Enabled</a>
```

or

```
<a id="Site_Gallery-563" class="switcher" href="#">Disabled</a>
```

What I would like todo is CSS, or maybe on the ajax call (not ideal) is look at that value and then set the link colour to either green or red.

I figured in CSS there might be away to-do

```
.switcher='Enabled' {
  color: green;
} .switch='Disabled' {
  color: red;
}
```

Are there any tricks to-do this? p.s thanks for your answers so far

Comment: Enabled how? Containing the word "enabled"?

Comment: The `<a>` tag does not have any attribute that can be "Enabled". What do you mean by "Enabled"?

Comment: Do not invent your own terms. It would only end up in ambiguity and nonsense. Rather describe in layman's terms in enduser perspective the steps how to achieve this. E.g. "When I put my mouse pointer above it" or "When I click the link" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't check the value of the element with straight CSS.  In jQuery it would look like:

```
$(function(){
    $(".switcher").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == "Enabled"){
            $(this).addClass("enabled");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("enabled");
        }
    });
});
```

and then in the CSS you can just look for the "enabled" class versus a "naked" switcher class:

```
.switcher{
    color:red;
}

.switcher.enabled{
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill make this its own function and then trigger it on the success.

Comment: fyi, it needs to be if ($(this).text() == "Enabled"){

Comment: @azz0r, yeah, thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed it just in case someone googles this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 val =  $('#toggleElement').val()
  if(val!==''){
   $('#toggleElement').css('color','green')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
$('a[enabled]').css('color', 'green');
```

is a step in the right direction, or maybe

```
$('a[enabled=true]').css('color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `:active` and `:focus` pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a#id').change(function() {
   $(this).css('color', 'green');
});
```

But it won't work, because you can't "change" a hyperlink html, not without another script. The function `change` is meant to be used with text input like the ones in the forms

Hope I have helped.

EDIT: Just got what you meant (I think). If by enabled, you mean when your mouse is over the link, the css pseudo-class `:hover` does that very well. Check it on google, you get tons of results

Answer (score 0):

Some case

if with `enabled` you mean

- *mouse* over it : use CSS `a#id:hover{...}`
- *mouse click* : use CSS `a#id:active{...}`
- *you are currently viewing the contents of the link* : you need to use jQuery to add a class after the link has been click (*if ajax*). or somehow parse the url, match it with the href of the link and add a class to it (*not recommended though .. better use server side scripts..*)

Answer (score -1):

Page on how to style links using css: http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm